# Как разделить значение столбца DF по условию?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть DataFrame с множеством столбцов, в одном из них 'age' часть данных вместо дней записана в часах. По данным сразу видно что данные свыше 1000 это часы.
Не могу понять как, с помощью pandas, поделить ячейки столбца, которые выполняют условие > 1000, на 24. не пойму куда и как указать условие

```
df['age'].apply(lambda x: x/24)
```

Comment: df['age'].apply(lambda x: x/24 if x >1000)

Comment: на такой код 
df['age'] = df['age'].apply(lambda x: x/24 if x >1000)
ругается SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если датафрейм:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"age":[1000, 10, 20, 2000,5]})
```

```
    age
0  1000
1    10
2    20
3  2000
4     5
```

то решение:

```
df['age'] = df['age'].apply(lambda x: x/24 if x>1000 else x)
```

```
           age
0  1000.000000
1    10.000000
2    20.000000
3    83.333333
4     5.000000
```